# Is it OK to check in a box that is not plain on the outside (e.g. there are printed pictures, etc. on the box)

Tags: luggage, airlines

It's a cardboard box that used to store my desktop computer. So the outside of the box is not plain and has printed pictures and words. I wonder if it's OK to use the box as a piece of checked luggage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, it's fine, I've shipped this baby as checked luggage multiple times:

[image]

They'll just stick the baggage label on the side.

My main concern was damage from baggage handling, getting wet, etc.  Tape it shut carefully, and a plastic bag on the inside would not hurt.  Ask for a fragile sticker at check-in, and they'll probably make you sign a disclaimer saying it's not the airline's problem if it breaks.

Comment: Just to add that I might stump up a couple of pounds (dollars / euros ......) to have a box like that shrink wrapped to protect against the elements.  I have sat on a plane a number of times and watched my luggage get soaked whilst on the Tarmac waiting to be loaded. Many airports offer the service, but if not you can get a small roll on a cardboard handle from mbe or similar stores.